# Graph of $f(x,y)=i$

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

Let $f:\Bbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ and $f(x,y)=i.$

So will the graph of this function be x-y plane?
Where it has 3 axis: x and y are real axis and z is the imaginary axis?
Basically somewhat like [Is this the Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDyxc.png)

I am in highschool and I was just curious because my teachers'answer wasn't satisfactory enough.

Comment: $i$ is not a real number so your first two statements contradict each other. Not just a nitpick—graphs of complex-valued functions are complicated.

Comment: The notation $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ means that $f$ is a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. Loosely speaking, $f$ is a "rule" which associates to each pair $(x,y)$ of real numbers, another real number. So it does not make sense to define $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ by $f(x,y)=i$, as $i$ is not a real number. You can, however, define the function $f: \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb C$ by $f(x,y)=i$. You could depict this function in the 3-dimensional plane. However, if instead you had a function like $g(x,y)=4+5i$, then it would no longer be possible to "draw" its graph.

Comment: @Joe but g(x,y) can be visualised via mapping atleast, right? And it should look like....(if possible)?

Comment: For visualization purposes, you can separate the real and imaginary parts of $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and "plot" $f$ by showing 3D plots of $u$ and $v$ side-by-side, like [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+log%28x%2Biy%29) tends to do. Or you can condense the information into a 2D contour plot, like [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) shows in some examples.

Comment: @æîōü: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "mapping"? In any case, you could visualise $g$ by drawing two $2$-dimensional planes side by side. Then you could draw arrows from the first plane to the second plane which go from each pair $(x,y)$ of real numbers in the first plane to the point $4+5i$ in the second plane. That's the best you can do, unless you can visualise $4$-dimensional space ;-) (By the way, our inability to visualise 4D is a physical limitation of humans – it does mean there is anything "special" about 4D from a mathematical perspective.)

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can understand your function is from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$. Both are two-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, so the graph lies in the four-dimensional space $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{C}$. It is
$$
    A = \left\{(x,y,i) \mid x,y \in \mathbb{R} \right\}
$$
It is a two-dimensional affine plane lying in four-dimensional space.

If you ignore one of those dimensions, you might be able to “see” the graph better. Replace $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ and $i$ with $1$. The graph of $f(x,y) = 1$ lies in three-dimensional space, and it's just the $xy$-plane shifted “up” by one unit. The graph of your complex $f$ is the same $xy$-plane shifted one in the $i$ direction.

Comment: Ah thank you got it!